AWS Resource Explorer not available in AWS Middle East (Bahrain)?
Per the document located at https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/10/aws-resource-explorer-additional-regions/, it's stated that the AWS Resource Explorer service is available in the AWS Middle East (Bahrain) region. However, I've encountered an issue while configuring Resource Explorer for multi-account search from the Master account. Despite enabling this region in the Master account settings, it doesn't appear in the list of available regions in the quick set up configuration. Does anyone have insights into why this might be occurring?

I tried to set up Resource Explorer for multi-account search from the Master account (AWS Resource Explorer ->settings->Create Configuration on Quick Setup )to have visibility of all resource across all the available regions From all the accounts in the AWS Organization.

Expectation was this set up Configures AWS Resource Explorer indexes in all targeted Regions.

But This failed to create index in this region AWS Middle East (Bahrain). As per the documents, it says AWS Resource Explorer service is available in the AWS Middle East (Bahrain.


